# Got test error when i tried to do a pull request

Tags: git, github, rake, travis-ci

I tried to do a pull request to a repo. The document who i edit in was in html.
But i got the messaged "The Travis build failed" and i check the Travis CI report, and this is the report error:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: What's the question? That error is very clear, and you haven't supplied any information about the project.

Comment: Maybe the version you forked from was not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that your .travis.yml file couldn't be parsed and we default the project to Ruby. We've changed some behaviour for this now so the build errors with a more sane error message ("your .travis.yml file couldn't be parsed" or something along those lines).

Sorry about the confusion.